# Get values from two select element and compare in another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get two values from different select elements and access those elements outside a function.

```
function firstValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("val-selec");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;  
  
  return strUser;
}

function secondValue(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("val-selec1");
    var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; 
  
  return strUser1;
}
        


if(firstValue() == "val1" && secondValue() == "val2"){
    //do something
}
```

when I log my function it just returns the first value it does not change when you select another option. What would be a way I can compare values and to a certain thing

https://jsfiddle.net/v50wdnL1/1/ I included a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why the `#onchange` events are calling function that only return values and dont do any meaningful operations. Instead make them both call a compare function and in that compare function call your other function which return the values. Example below:

HTML:

```html
<select name="val-select" id="val-selec" onchange="compare();">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="val1">val1</option>
  <option value="val2">val2</option>
  <option value="val3">val3</option>
  <option value="val4">val4</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="val-select1" id="val-selec1" onchange="compare();">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="val1">val1</option>
  <option value="val2">val2</option>
  <option value="val3">val3</option>
  <option value="val4">val4</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function firstValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("val-selec");
    return e.value;
}

function secondValue(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("val-selec1");
    return e1.value
}
        
function compare(){
    var value1 = firstValue();
    var value2 = secondValue();
    console.log(value1 === value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so, I think your code fails because you have a typo (depending where you want to put that `if(condition){do_something()}`, you are trying to access `e` when you should access `e1` in the function `secondValue()`

I think you can get away without declaring those functions for the values like so:

```
function my_action(){
  let firstValue  = document.querySelector('#val-selec').value;
  let secondValue = document.querySelector('#val-selec1').value;
  if(firstValue == "val1" && secondValue == "val2"){
  //do something

  }
}
```

and then execute that func when u change the select:

```
<select name="val-select" id="val-selec" onchange="my_action();">
```

I hope is useful